# Illegal instruction: 4 when importing python plugins

Tags: python, c++, operating-system

I tried to install a `hoomd`_script molecular dynamics software on my imac (it's imac pro before 2009, the system is `OS X El captain v10.11.3`). I have successfully compiled this to iMac, but when I import this hoomd_script in `Python 2.7.12`, Python crashes completely and I get the error:

`Illegal instruction: 4`.

I have installed all the prerequisites packages (including `boost`, `sphinx`, `git`, `mpich2`, `numpy`, `cmake`, `pkg-config`, `sqlite`) using `conda`.

I applied `python -vc 'hoomd_script'` to test, and the result is [here](http://pastebin.com/WXUSeiwA). I tried to reinstall all the packages including `conda` and recompile the `hoomd`, but nothing changed. I wonder how can I fix this. Thanks!

Comment: Not a Mac user, but could `Illegal instruction` have something to do with the processor being 32 or 64 bit, and then trying to execute a program for the wrong architecture?

Answer (score 0):

As stated on the [HOOMD-blue web page](http://glotzerlab.engin.umich.edu/hoomd-blue/download.html), the conda builds require a CPU capable of AVX instructions (2011 or newer). The illegal instruction results because you are trying to execute an instruction that your processor does not support.

Compiling hoomd from a clean build directory on your system should result in a binary that your system can execute. Note that conda provided prerequisite libraries are difficult to work with: I recommend using macports or homebrew.